# Server Client application in c using TCP/IP protocol

Tags: c, windows, ubuntu, server, client

> Hi, I am developing Server client between two different operating
>   systems. I am executing server on Ubuntu 14.04 & Client on Windows.

```
/* Simple Server code on TCP/IP protocol */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ctype.h>          
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define length 512
void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno; //Declare variable for Socket and port
     socklen_t clilen;  //Client address and port no
     char buffer[length];   //Buffer for message

     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;    //Srtructure for server and Client address
     int n; //Check whether listen,accept,read,write process done
     FILE *fileptr; //File pointer
     int datasize;

    /* Check Portno. provided or not */
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }

    /*Create socket*/
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");

     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); //Clear memory for Server address 
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);    //Convert portno in to Integer from ASCII

    /*Server address and all other details */
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    /*Bind socket*/
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");

    /*Listening to socket and waiting for users(max.5) */
     listen(sockfd,5);

     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr); //Size of Client address

    /*Accept users*/
     newsockfd= accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,&clilen);
     if (newsockfd< 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");


    /*File operations */
    char* fs_name = "/home/ankur/Desktop/RTSIM_Dump.csv";   
     fileptr=fopen(fs_name,"r");    //Open file

    /*Write and Read operation to socket*/

    bzero(buffer,length);
    while((datasize = fread(buffer,sizeof(char),length,fileptr))>0)
    {
        if(send(newsockfd,buffer,datasize,0)<0)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to send file :%s (errno = %d)\n",fs_name,errno);
            break;
        }
        bzero(buffer,length);
    }


     fclose(fileptr);   //Close file
     close(newsockfd);  //Close to accept client
     close(sockfd); //close socket


     return 0; 
}


//Client code:
------------------------------------------------------------------------------#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "2222"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    char sendbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen;
    FILE *fileptr;

    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


//Receive file from Server and save it.

        fileptr = fopen("/Desktop/RTSIM_Dump.csv","w");
        if (fileptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("ERROR:Create/Open file");
            exit(1);
        }
        int write_sz;
        memset(recvbuf,0,DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
        while((recvbuflen = recv(ConnectSocket,recvbuf,DEFAULT_BUFLEN,0))>0)
        {
            write_sz = fwrite(recvbuf,sizeof(char),recvbuflen,fileptr);
            if(write_sz < recvbuflen)
            {
                printf("File write failed.\n");
            }
                memset(recvbuf,0,DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
                if(recvbuflen == 0 || recvbuflen != 512)
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
        if(recvbuflen < 0)
        {
                printf("recv() timed out.\n");
        }

    // cleanup
    fclose(fileptr);
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ I am getting errno 104 on server (Ubuntu) & create/open file error on
>   Windows.
>
> Thanks in advance!!!
>
> I checked server client on Ubuntu , it works perfectly but when i
>   tried it with Windows client. It gives me error during execution.

Comment: Do you really have a `/Desktop` directory on your windows machine?

Comment: I made silly mistake. But on server side its still give errno 104

Answer (score 0):

```
fileptr = fopen("/Desktop/RTSIM_Dump.csv","w");
```

That is incorrect path for windows. More proper would be `"\Desktop\RTSIM_Dump.csv"`. Note that the directories in the path must exist and have appropriate permissions.

Where do you get error 104 in server?

Comment: The 104 (connection reset by peer) most likely comes in `send` (from the client connecting but dying right away with the file error before receiving anything).

Comment: Yes, in server i am getting errno 104.

Comment: I made change on Client code as suggested me. It works but now client receives only 1.9 KB. My file is have data more than it.